# How to change IDLDE background color?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I was just wondering if/how I could change the background color of IDLDE, to avoid having a white screen all day long, and use a less exhausting color for my eyes like brown/grey...
Thanks a lot

EDIT : IDLDE (the IDL IDE) not IDLE, my bad, I'm working with IDLE and IDLDE...

Comment: Have you tried changing the !P.BACKGROUND value?  I assume you are talking about the plotting window, correct?  Determine what color table you are using, then determine which value corresponds to black and set !P.BACKGROUND to this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `right-clicking` on the editor window, and hit **Preferences**. At the bottom, under **Appearance color options** select **Background color** and uncheck System Default. Then, you can play with the little color box just above it.

Works for me in IDL 8.3.0.